# Unmatching Database restore path

Tags: sql-server

I am restoring a database in SSMS using command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE name
FROM DISK = '...' 
WITH REPLACE, STATS =25
(the path is an UNC path)
```

Before the job runs fine in sql server agent, this job failed just now because of some external reasons, now no matter either I tried to run the query in SSMS command window or the scheduled job in sql server agent, it gives the error message, says:

Directory lookup for the file "D:..." same for the log backup

How the restoring process try to look for the .bak files on 'D'drive instead of the specified UNC path? I double checked all .bak files are there. Why it's trying to look for a different backup path? lol

Comment: please provide clear reasons..this doesn't help `it gives the error message, says:` what does it say ?

Comment: it says: Directory lookup for the file "D:..."  which means the restore job was trying to locate the .bak on D drive, but I do specify the restore path which is that UNC path right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you backup database,it backups path of its old data files and log files.So when you don't specify restore path,it tries to restore it in old path on current server..

so try to provide explicit naming  and use with move option

Example using Adventure works

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups  
   WITH NORECOVERY,   
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO   
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.mdf',   
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log'   
TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.ldf';
```

Comment: The backup job backs up the database to that UNC path, and the restore job did specify the restore path which is using 'FROM DISK', am I correct? or I am missing something?

Comment: You have one more log file or data file in same path ,try using move with rename